# Checking Equivalence of a Stack element and a char

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I want to check weather the element at the top of a stack is equals to a char in a string. How would I go about doing it? I know that this isn't right:

```
if (stack.peek() != str.charAt(i)) {}
```

and I'm pretty certain stacks don't have an `.equals()` method.

Comment: how is your `stack` object created?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? It seems OK to me and about the only sensible way to do it. How do you define your stack, though?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Stack` of `String` then here's the sample code:

```
Stack<String> st = new Stack<>();
        st.add("s");

        if(st.peek().equals(String.valueOf("sasda".charAt(0)))) {
            System.out.println("blah blah");
        }
```

**N.B:**

1) Even if you are using `String` only `equals()` is not enough because you're comparing `char` with `String` here(`stack.peek() != str.charAt(i)`). So you need to compare either `String` or `char`.

2) If you're using custom `POJO` then you'll be using `getter` for comparison.

Hope it's clear.